# Playing videos on iPad with a specific style

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-streaming

i have some mp4 files which are to be played in my iPad app.. I am able to do that quite well. right now i have a play button on blank black space in my app and the video plays after i tap the play button. The user will only come to know the content of the video after playing it.. But, i want the user to know about the video before playing itself . instead of the default black screen i want to show the video starting screen to make the video more interesting. To put it in simple words, i want my video space to be similar to youtube... IS there any way i which this can be done??  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `MPMoviePlayerController` (or however you're playing your video.. if you already use a custom class just add the code in there) and in `viewDidAppear` initialise a `UIImageView` with frame size equal to `self.view.bounds` using whatever background image you want for the loading screen. Add the `UIImageView` as a subview of `self.view` and call `sendSubviewToBack:` on it. When the player is ready to play, it will start drawing video frames on top of your subview, and you should not see it again.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
  UIImageView *loadingImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
  [loadingImage setFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [self.view addSubview:loadingImage];
  [self.view sendSubviewToBack:loadingImage];
  [super viewDidAppear];
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) If you're using this method then you should accept the answer too.